# how to fix libgmp and libmpfr mismatch during configure

Tags: linux, build, makefile, configure

I am facing this issue with compiling gnuplot but I believe this is more general issue. 
The compiler is picking non-compatible version of gmp and mpfr pairs of library. Not sure what to pass to configure so as to fix this.

Right now my system libgmp and libmpfr in both /usr/lib and /usr/local/lib. Two versions of mpfr so.1.2 and so.4 are installed on the system. But the compiler picks up  so.4.

Playing around with LDFLAGS didn't solve the problem. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have several versions of a library you should make sure the `.so` compilation link points to the right one, i.e. in this case, `libmpfr.so` should point to `libmpfr.so.1.2`.

Comment: that should have worked but the  compiler is picking up libmpfr.so.4 by default...not sure why..